# AMD A6-3420M resolution widder than it should be

Tags: ati, graphics, resolution, screen

Using a screen resolution(1366*768) from the amd config privative driver looks wider than it should be, I don’t know if this is a bug or there’s something that I can do to fix it

*my specs:*

- dual graphics amd 6520g 6470m
- apu amd a6-3420m
- catalyst omega

[here's a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0UbK.jpg) starting chrome(maximized). Look at the left side and right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the way Compiz is displaying the window. Try right-clicking in the empty space to the left of the new tab button, then select "Use system title bar and borders".

Comment: i feel it wider because the pointer can hide at 100% when i place it to the rigth (totally hide)

Answer (score 0):

OP's original solution:

DISABLE HARDWARE ACCELERATION

Answer (score 0):

This a very tough problem with this kind of dual graphics.

AMD proprietary drivers do not support this integrated adapter.

Open source drivers generally do not deal great with AMD dual graphics.

I would suggest to try Ubuntu 15.04. It has the latest opensource graphical stack, that may solve this issue. Or maybe not.